# How to add TSLint to VSCode Default Build task?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, tslint, vscode-tasks

I have installed [TSLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) to VS Code.

In my angular app, how can I update VS Code to run TSLint against my source when I run the default build task?

Answer (score 3):

TSLint for VS code is a visual help, not a build tool. Don't mix it up.

If you want to add a linter to your default build task, this will happen in your `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "ng build --prod"
}
```

replace this line with

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "ng lint; ng build --prod"
}
```

Now you can run

```
npm run build
```

and your project will lint before building.

Comment: Yes, a linter runs static analysis. I want to run it prebuild locally. I don't want to add it to the package.json, since that will affect builds in the integration/deployment pipeline. I want to add it to VSCode's Build Tasks, so it's integrated with a keystroke and I can add `-fix` and review changes before committing.

Comment: Well I have the extension too, and from the commands I can run, the only thing it does is checking your linting and outputting it to the console. So my answer would be **no**, you can't do what you want. But I've never used VSCode building tools, so who knows. And either solution will affect the integration/deployement pipeline since you want to run it pre-build and cancel the build if the linting doesn't pass ... And by the way, if you use continuous integration, it's better to have it in your package file rather than in your IDE.

Comment: " if you use continuous integration, it's better to have it in your package file rather than in your IDE."

Not if you're running `-fix` which will make changes to files outside of your source control, so your build output for CI isn't the same as local, which could subtle debugging trouble.

Comment: What's this `-fix` you're talking about ? A suffix to your commits ? a NG flag ? And I'm saying this because you won't have VSCode on your Jenkins or Travis. So really, I don't understand what you're talking about ...

Comment: It's a flag to the ng cli `ng lint`: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/lint 
"`--fix` Fixes linting errors (may overwrite linted files)."
Automatically fixes simple things it finds.

Comment: Yeah so simply run `ng lint --fix; git commit -a -m "Lint fix"; ng build --prod` ...

Comment: @StuperUser (Although I don't recommend fixing the errors automatically)